# Netbeans 7.3 doesn't save java project settings

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to enable WebStart in my Java project (NetBeans 7.3, Ubuntu 12.10 64x)

I go to Project Properties -> WebStart, enable it and click Ok.

Next time I go to that page - check box is unchecked again.
And it builds regular Java project, not JNLP.
So WebStart is not on.

Does anyone have same issue?

I tried to reinstall NetBeans, tried to reboot the PC - same thing.
Tried to google it, but no one seems to experience this.

Comment: Did you try running NetBeans as sudo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have same behavior with IcedTea Java vm.
On Oracle Java vm WebStart check box saved properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass this bug by changing the project properties manually.
Just go into your project folder, then `nbproject` and open the file `project.properties`. There is a key `jnlp.enabled` which you have to set on true.

Answer (score 0):

Installed NetBeans 7.2.1 and it worked.